# How to create attributes with different names each time?

Tags: python, attributes

(python, pygame)
There's a moment in my code where multiples attributes are created, and I want them to each have a different name. I think that's called creating dynamically maybe ??

```
        for row, tiles in enumerate(self.mapData):
        for colone, tile in enumerate(tiles):
            if tile == 'w':
                self.wall = Wall(self,colone, row)

            if tile == '8':
                self.camera = Camera(self, colone, row, "up")
            if tile == '2':
                self.camera = Camera(self, colone, row, "down")
            if tile == '6':
                self.camera = Camera(self, colone, row, "right")
            if tile == '4':
                self.camera = Camera(self, colone, row, "left")
```

So I want that each created camera has a different name but I don't know how to do that.
This is for modifying each and every of them here.

```
            if self.camera.x <= self.player.x < self.camera.x1 and self.camera.y <= 
            self.player.y < self.camera.y1:
                print("detecté")
                self.alive = False
```

I've tried using pygame's groups but it didn't worked.
So please could I have any help ?

Comment: why don't you append the instances of Camera to a list and later iterate over the list? it is a bit confusing why you are overriding previous values of the instance attribute `camera` but that is what you are doing. `self.camera` will refer to the `Camera` created based on the value of the last tile

Comment: use list of cameras and append each Camera object to this list